# Got Stuck In Deploying Laravel App With Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bitbucket-pipelines

we are trying to deploy laravel app(which contains api's) and vue js app(contains full front end).both are in seperate folders how to deploy through bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: cpanel or VPS ...

Comment: Virtual Private Server(vps)

Answer (score 0):

The best work around is for you to have a laravel image and docker image separately. You can then push the images to docker hub and create containers on the server using the latest images.  You can also consider using [watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) to help in updating you containers everytime we have a new images available in dockerhub.